# Implement combinational logic using control input

Tags: digital-logic

I need to implement the following block.

[image]

LD comes from a clocked control input but Adder and Score Register must be built using sequential logic. 
When control outputs 1, I load my score into Score Register but I don't know how to stop/freeze it because once LD is 1, I will be adding Score Register's output with the BUS, then load and then add it and so on.

How do I make my combinational circuit execute loading only once?

Answer (score 1):

I think your only option is to use an edge triggered register like the 74173. Otherwise the circuit does not reach a stable state as you described.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [pulse detector circuit](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_4/chpt_10/5.html) to convert the latch signal into a clock signal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjSdL9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>